# merge two text file in one without duplicate header in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two files that looks like this:

```
file1.txt

ID group gender age
a 1 m 55
b 1 f 54
c 2 m 53
... etc


file2.txt

ID group gender age
l 1 m 64
m 2 f 94
n 2 m 93
... etc
```

Desired output:

```
ID group gender age
a 1 m 55
b 1 f 54
c 2 m 53
.
l 1 m 64
m 2 f 94
n 2 m 93
.
```

Which means to the header only show once.I tried `head -n 1 file1.txt > merge.txt; tail -n +2 -q *.txt >> merge.txt`, In my real file1.txt has 87394750 row and file2.txt has 369765446 rows,it's spend a lot of time.Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: `*.txt` includes `merge.txt` so you are appending `merge.txt` to itself over and over again

Comment: @jhnc,Oh okay, now I get it! Nowonder I've waited for so long! Thank you.

Comment: note that this will only happen with files bigger than a certain size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cp` then `sed`:

```
cp file1.txt merge.txt; sed 1d file2.txt >> merge.txt
```

`sed 1d` skips the first line.

To skip more lines, use `sed 1,nd`, where n is the total number of lines to skip.

Comment: or `awk 'FNR>1'` is longer but lets you strip headers from multiple files

Answer (score 2):

A bash-only solution using `cat`, redirection and `tail` (within a *process substitution*) can be done with:

```bash
cat file1.txt <(tail -n+2 file2.txt) > merged.txt
```

Where `merged.txt` would contain:

```
$ cat file1.txt <(tail -n+2 file2.txt) > merged.txt

$ cat merged.txt
ID group gender age
a 1 m 55
b 1 f 54
c 2 m 53
...
l 1 m 64
m 2 f 94
n 2 m 93
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'FNR==1 && FILENAME=="file2" {next}1' file1 file2
ID group gender age
a 1 m 55
b 1 f 54
c 2 m 53
... 
l 1 m 64
m 2 f 94
n 2 m 93
...
```